# Android Moshi: what's the development status

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

I remember [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) being presented as the upgrade to (Google's) [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for Android from the creators of Gson themselves (in Square), with better performances and better support for Kotlin.

However, the latest release is now almost a year old, and even though there is activity in the repository, Gson still seems way more active and, according to AppBrain, much more adopted by developers in new projects.

What's the real story? Can anybody shed some light on the future of the two libraries?

Comment: *Can anybody shed some light on the future of the two libraries?*  maybe the creators  or a fairy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moshi is the future. It's the only one of these two libraries with significant Kotlin features. It has active contributors and a lot of [recent commits](https://github.com/square/moshi/graphs/commit-activity).

Comment: Thank you Jesse. I was mainly wondering because, as I mentioned, the last release happened almost a year ago. I will keep an eye on updates.

Comment: Moshi 1.6 was released today!